# Unordered map with multiple values

Tags: c++, unordered-map

So I have an unordered map, and for each key I want to store two unique floats. These floats represent aggregate values over time of something I am simulating, and thus as my code progresses they values of existing keys may be added to, and new keys may be created.

Previously I was only tracking one value, and so an unordered map was the easy solution. I am not sure how to save two distinct values with one key though?

- Using an `unordered_map<int,vector<float> >` was my first thought, but then adding to existing values isn't as easy. It seems I must determine if a key exists first, and then either add the new vector component-wise to the existing one or set the key equal to the new vector.
- I looked at unordered_multimap. Although I didn't get a great feel for how it works, it didn't seem to offer a good way to track which of the values is which, given that I have two values that I want to keep separate and be able to determine which is which.

Is there another way to go about this?

---

Using `unordered_map<int,pair<float,float> >` was an easy solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "determine which is which"? Do you need to know the order they were inserted into the map?

Comment: If I understand correctly, what's wrong with an `unordered_map<int, std::pair<float,float>>`. That maps pretty well "for each key I want to store two unique floats". A pair lets you keep track of the floats with `first` and `second`. Keep in mind though that you should be definitely sure that you must store two and only two floats. This solution doesn't evolve.

Comment: The answer is probably `unordered_multimap`, Can you clarify how it lacks "great feel" and "good way"?

Comment: @MarkRansom Not so much the order as much as some way to distinguish to two values. I.e. at the end of the code I have two values for a key - say values A and B - and I want some way to collect all of the A-values and all of the B-values form all keys.

Comment: @JBL That works perfect - hadn't used that type before.

Comment: Seems to me, that the problem has not been well defined. Could you add a source code example, or shown some values, with the keys examples, and the pair values examples ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `unordered_map< int, std::pair< float, float > >`, accessing the values via the `.first` and `.second` functions of the pair.  I'm not sure that that is "easier" then using the `vector< float >` approach though.  The vector approach has the advantage of allowing you to expand to store more values with ease.  The `pair` approach has the advantage of being explicitly two values and only two values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `vector` and `pair` as mentioned. You can also consider creating a `struct` if the number of values is fixed. This may be easier when you have multiple values from multiple data types in a single record.

```
struct Data {
 float value1;
 float value2;
};

unordered_map<int, Data> myMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple of variable length

```
#include<iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include<map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    // Defining Map  with two two values 
    map <string, tuple<int, int>> g1;

    g1.insert({"camera1", make_tuple(10,20)});
    g1.insert({"camera2", make_tuple(100,208)});
    g1.insert({"camera3", make_tuple(1000,202)});
    g1.insert({"camera4", make_tuple(102,202)});
    g1.insert({"camera5", make_tuple(104,203)});
    g1.insert({"camera6", make_tuple(109,203)});

    //print map g1
    cout<<"\nThe map g1 is : \n";
    cout <<"\n Key\tElement \n";
    
    string val = "camera7";
    
    // // Find the specific key is present if not add that
    map<string,tuple<int, int>>::iterator itr;
    
    itr = g1.find("camera7");

    if(itr ==g1.end())
    {
        cout << "Key-value pair not present in map \n" ;
        g1.insert({val, make_tuple(200,192)});
    }
    else
    {   cout<<itr->first;
        cout<<"x: "<< get<0>((itr->second));
        cout<<"y: "<< get<1>((itr->second));
    }

    // //updated value 
    cout<<"Updated Value\n";
    cout <<"\n \tKey\t\tElement1\tElement2 \n";
    for (itr=g1.begin(); itr!=g1.end();itr++)
    {
        cout<<"\t"<<itr->first<<"\t"<< get<0>(itr->second)<< " \t\t"<<get<1>(itr->second)<<"\n";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```